# How and why did Scott Lang shrink in this way?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015

In the movie *Ant-Man*, at 01:35:50, Scott shrinks himself to fight Darren Cross, aka Yellow Jacket.

He shrinks himself upwards. So he is in the air when he shrinks completely and then he falls on the ground.

Why did he shrink himself that way? Why didn't he shrink himself downwards in order to prevent the falling?

Comment: Because he shrinks/enlarges to the center of his mass...not up or down.

Comment: It happens the same throughout that whole movie, at least. It’s just how it works, presumably to centre of mass as Paulie_D says.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I always assumed it was around the belt, because that is where the regulator (with the Pym particle inside) is located, and the centre of mass was just a coincedence, or Hank deliberately designed it like that so that changing size doesn't throw the user off balance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible to control which point to shrink to. It's just that Scott was not practiced enough at the time, because in *Ant-Man 2* at 1:33:00 in the fight with Ghost, Hope and Scott were able to shrink both upwards and downwards.